# Recovery of an ASP.NET MVC application and Entity Framework upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

A client had a developer leave abruptly, and did they did not leave any source code for a project. So, I have been tasked with de-compiling the dll, and rebuilding the project.

I have a fairly clean de-compile and I have been copying classes and stuff into a new ASP.NET MVC project shell. I believe the previous project was using Entity Framework since there are connection strings in the `web.config` that use EF attributes.

One of the items I do not have for this project is the EDMX file and all associated generated classes and templates. The compile code has all the data classes. So I am wondering a couple things.

Can I strip out any possible reference to the database first EDMX patterns and instead convert the de-compiled data classes to code first with migrations? (I would prefer)

Ryan

Comment: Well, if you have the database, you can do [code first from an existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database).

Comment: Hmm, great point, I did not consider that. I do have the database, but I am not 100% sure this code is up to date with that schema.

Comment: If the code is not up to date with the schema then it shouldn't be functional currently.  It would require updating either way.